# Install4j installer doesn't see mapped drive when it's bundled with another installer

Tags: windows, install4j, mapped-drive

I'm having this weird issue where my install4j generated installer doesn't detect my mapped drives in Windows. I believe that this has to do with some elevated privileges settings, but I can't seem to figure out where the problem might be.

My installer is a bundled installer that is consisted of two installers. One base installer bundled with an addon installer.  Here are some of the things that I have determined when testing.

- If I run the base installer by itself, I **can** see my mapped drives.
- If I run the bundled installer the combined the base and addon installer, I **can not** see my mapped drives.
- Both of the Request Privileges settings are the same settings:

  ```
    <action id="22" beanClass="com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RequestPrivilegesAction" actionElevationType="none" rollbackBarrierExitCode="0">
      <serializedBean>
        <property name="failIfNotRootUnix" type="boolean" value="true" />
        <property name="obtainIfAdminMac" type="boolean" value="true" />
        <property name="obtainIfNormalMac" type="boolean" value="true" />
        <property name="obtainIfNormalWin" type="boolean" value="true" />
      </serializedBean>
    </action>
  ```
- I have tried Install4j version 7.0.11 and 8.0.2 to see if it made any difference, but the results were the same between both versions.

Was curious if anyone else ran into this problem before or know of any other places to check out to figure out why my bundled installer doesn't see my mapped drives.

Comment: It is not clear what the difference between "base installer" and "base installer bundled with and addon installer" is. Is one of these installers invoked through a "Run executable" action in install4j?

Comment: Hey @IngoKegel, thanks for responding. The "base installer" does all the installation for my program and that's the one that's invoked through the "Run executable" action.  The "addon installer" can't exist by itself, it's just bundled on top of the base installer and customizes some settings from the base installer.  So if we run the "base installer" or the "bundled installer" it'll always invoke the "Run executable" that's created from the base installer side.  I hope that makes sense, sorry for it being a little convoluted.

Comment: So the execution environment for your two cases is essentially the same, just with different project files? Maybe you are using a different JRE in both cases?

Comment: They're using the same JRE in both cases.  I have a custom JRE loaded on a nexus repo that's being referenced and pulled down each time the installers are being built.

Comment: I'm afraid it is impossible to say what causes the difference with this information. You would have to try to make one installer more and more similar to the other until they both behave the same, then the last change before the behavior changes would give an indication what causes the difference.